# Framework downgrade : System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal (from 4.5 to 4.0)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade a asp.net (VB) project from 4.5 to 4.0. The only error left is an undefined call to "System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal". Is there any equivalent in the 4.0 framework ?

Code :

```
Dim p As New System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(New AppIdentity(user, True))
HttpContext.Current.User = p
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = p
```

Comment: This namespace is avaible only for Framework .NET 4.5+

Comment: Hi, thanks, i did understand that before posting, i'm just looking for some other way to replace the code ^^ But thanks anyway.

Comment: Instead of Claims, you should downgrade this for the legacy Identy Model http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftx85f8x(v=vs.110).aspx